# withCredentials not working in next js serverSide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies

Below is my code for axios interceptors, i have added withCredentials as true, which works fine on client side requests. i have checked this using chrome dev tools that i am getting cookies added in request. But for server side calls, no cookie is added to request, eventhough all requests uses below inceptors. Is there any other way i can add cookies to request or something i am doing wrong ?

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  timeout: AXIOS_TIMEOUT,
  baseURL:apiUrl,
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent(AGENT_CONFIG),
  httpAgent: new http.Agent(AGENT_CONFIG)
});

axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL =apiUrl;
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  config.withCredentials = true;
  const jwtToken = apiRequest.token();
  const { token: jwtNewToken = '' } = await jwtManager(jwtToken) || {};
  apiRequest.token = () => jwtNewToken;

  const token = apiRequest.token();

  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

  return config;
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Tried adding debugger on server to check if server side calls are getting cookies or not. they were not getting cookies in request

Comment: please reformat